# Loading a Java Charset manually

Tags: java, character-encoding, jakarta-mail, utf-7

I'm doing some work using the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) API, and I've run across encodings which Java doesn't support natively (by design), such as UTF7/unicode-1-1-utf-7. For that encoding in particular I found the [JUTF7](http://jutf7.sourceforge.net/) implementation of a Java `Charset` and `CharsetProvider` for UTF7. However, having added the jutf7.jar to my classpath I still get `UnsupportedEncodingException`s, and unicode-1-1-utf-7 is definitely one of JUTF7's aliases.

Is there a way to manually load the `Charset` or ensure that the `Charset` is being loaded so that I can rule that out as a cause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bit more to using a new Charset, apart from putting the necessary classes into the classpath. To quote the Javadocs:

> A charset provider identifies itself
>   with a provider-configuration file
>   named
>   java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider
>   in the resource directory
>   META-INF/services. The file should
>   contain a list of fully-qualified
>   concrete charset-provider class names,
>   one per line. [...]

( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html )

Is this special file present in the JAR?

Comment: That was the issue, thanks! In my efforts to avoid installing Apache Maven I did some quick source migration. I accidentally left the special file out of the jar as a result. I've built a jar with Maven, now, and the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure the jar is loaded by the main classloader. You can achieve this by adding the jar to the JVM's `jre/lib/ext` extension directory, or by adding it to the classpath of the main program. For example if you are using Tomcat, add `-cp /path/to/jutf7.jar` to Tomcat's startup script.

Similarly, if you want to test jutf7 from the scala REPL, you need to start it as follows

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-cp /path/to/jutf7-1.0.0.jar" scala
```

Tested with `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)`