# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: unicode-1-1-utf-7?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, java, utf

Looks like OpenJDK can't handle unicode-1-1-utf-7? How can we remedy that?

```
Caused by: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: unicode-1-1-utf-7
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(StreamDecoder.java:71)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:100)
        at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:109)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Loading a Java Charset manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308587/loading-a-java-charset-manually)

Comment: You can download a UTF7 implementation jar file from a third party such as 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jutf7
Copy the jar file to the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` directory and restart the probe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, UTF-7 is not a Java supported encoding: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Workaround:
 1. Download a jar in http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/ 
 2. Put a jar implementation of this encoding in your buildpath/classpath