# Change encoding from T1

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I want to change encoding from T1 to UTF-8 in Java.
I read and parse pdf to String using Tika. Then I change the ecoding using decode and encode methods in Charset class. There is no problem with common encodings like windows-1252 or UTF-8, but I cannot find class with T1 encoding.

Text sample:

```
Przykªady zastosowa«
```

I can properly decode this text on this page:
http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php

Comment: Seeing that the [T1 (Cork) encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_encoding) is not that difficult, you could build your own class.

Comment: I think that creating your own Cork Charset and a [CharsetProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html) and [loading it manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308587/loading-a-java-charset-manually) would be the best way to go.