# How to convert a regular string format (ascii?) to UTF-7 in JavaScript or Java?

Tags: javascript, java, utf-8, utf, utf-7

So I'm trying to understand how a special character normally seen as '<' could be converted to '+ADw-' in UTF-7.

Is there an online tool or a built in library in JavaScript or Java that can do this?

What is the math behind this? I know that UTF-7 uses 7bits to store the character, so I am guessing that the '+ADw-' is just the numerical representation of '<' in ASCII? Meaning, if you converted to '<' to a number, that would be equal to '+ADw-' as a number?

Thanks!

Comment: No, UTF-7 uses one byte to store a 7-bit value, which is either the entire codepoint or some of its 21 bits, depending on the codepoint being encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Java itself does not have UTF-7 support.

But that [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jutf7/) provides a UTF-7 charset implementation and when you add its jar to your Java application you can simply write:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-7");
out.write("<");
```

to see how a string is translated into UTF-7.

Comment: Hey I tried using that but when I looked in the source of the jutf7 library it doesn't have a OutputStreamWriter, it uses java.io.OutputStreamWriter: Using this code I get no result, but I didnt just include the jar though, I copied all the src into my Test project in eclipse:

Comment: import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;


public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  OutputStreamWriter out;
  try {
   out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-7");
   out.write("<");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}

Comment: Yes the `OutputStreamWriter` in my example is `java.io.OutputStreamWriter`. Copying the sources to your project might not be enough. If you look into the `jutf7-1.0.0.jar` there is also a file `META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider` which is needed to register the UTF-7 charset. Therefore include this file as resource to your project or simply use the jar.

Comment: Following the usage info in the src, I get bad results too: java -jar jutf7-1.0.0.jar encode <
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

java -jar jutf7-1.0.0.jar encode a
a

C:\Downloads\jutf7-1.0.0\jutf7-1.0.0>java -jar jutf7-1.0.0.jar enc
de b
b

C:\Downloads\jutf7-1.0.0\jutf7-1.0.0>java -jar jutf7-1.0.0.jar enc
de ss
ss

C:\Downloads\jutf7-1.0.0\jutf7-1.0.0>java -jar jutf7-1.0.0.jar enc
de 1
1

C:\Downloads\jutf7-1.0.0\jutf7-1.0.0>java -jar jutf7-1.0.0.jar enc
de <
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: wero, thank you so much for your guidance. I added the jar AND the src to the build path of the sample project in eclipse but its still not displaying anything. I will continue to tinker around with this and keep you posted.

Comment: I think this post/person is having/was having the same issue I have now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308587/loading-a-java-charset-manually