# Load a Java Charset explicitly, dynamically

Tags: java, dependency-injection

This is not a repeat of [Loading a Java Charset manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308587/loading-a-java-charset-manually).  I want to do the same thing, but without using META-INF.  Is it possible?  Is a general solution for various service types?

In this specific case, I need to process utf-7 data, using a CharsetProvider like [JUTF7](http://jutf7.sourceforge.net/).  In addition to adding the jar to the classpath, this requires adding a file to META-INF/services, where the file name is java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider and the contents identifies jutf7.  However, it is not possible to use META-INF in this case.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Why is it not possible to use META-INF?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to register a new `CharSet`, other than by implementing a [`CharSetProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html), and it can only be registered thru `META-INF/services`. See the javadoc.

However, that doesn't mean that *you* have to provide that file for jutf7. The jutf7 jar file already has the necessary service file. As the page you linked says: *Just drop the jar in your classpath, and you are ready to go.*

Comment: Thanks for the tip, which suggested a workaround.  Unfortunately, it fails because the system class loader is not the same class loader used to load user-imported classes, in my case, and the character set provider service uses the system class loader directly.  There's a solution involving reflection but it's not pretty.

Comment: That is an ancient unresolved bug: [JDK-4619777 : (cs) Charset providers are not looked up via the context class loader](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4619777)